# Is there anyway to create screen space for Plank dock like in Mac OS X?

Tags: dock, plank

I want Plank to work like the dock in Mac OS X (and Gnome Panel-Docklet 13) so that maximised windows won't cover the dock.

[Doc in Mac OS X http://www.gellocunan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/MacOS4.jpg](http://www.gellocunan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/MacOS4.jpg)

Comment: welcome to askubuntu. In order to get community members to answer your questions, they should contain all relevant information. In this case, you should explain what you mean by "Plank dock like in Macintosh", because some of us do not use Macs. A picture might be helpful.

Comment: @xubuntix I think he means he's trying to achieve an effect with the Plank such that maximized windows won't overlap with it onscreen. On Mac OS X, if you maximize a window, the bottom of the window only goes as far as the top of the dock, leaving the dock and wallpaper clearly visible.

Comment: I know you could do something like this with Docky, which the Plank is based on, but it's been a long time since I last used Docky and I don't know what changes to settings may have been made for the Plank since I don't use that either.

Comment: @mateo_salta that would raise the dock as well

Comment: there must be another way though, I can set bottom margin in openbox with obconf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in cairo dock
Just selct `Reserve space for dock`
[image]
Thats it.

Just as you wanted

[image]
[image]

---

#### Install `Cairo dock`

By ppa

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa`
> `sudo apt-get update`
> `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins`

Comment: @LumTechBuilder Glad to help